# playn not playing with mvn, ironically

Tags: macos, maven, terminal, playn

Trying to run the basic examples given by playn, wanting to have a go with the toolkit. I'm following the instructions as given here: http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted

However, after doing a clone and running mvn compile exec:java from the command line it comes up with the following response:

mvn compile exec:java

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-core:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/keitama/Sites/Games/playn-samples/showcase/core/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.googlecode.playn:playn-project:pom:1.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase:1.0-SNAPSHOT, /Users/username/Sites/Games/playn-samples/showcase/pom.xml, line 6, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Totally lost now. I've taken a look at the help pages given, but they're just talking another language to me, it seems. Being a complete starter to both Maven and playn, I'm all over the place. HELP!

Cheers :)

EDIT:

After a pull and following instructions below, the following error comes up:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/username/Sites/Games/playn-samples/showcase/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.googlecode.playn:playn-project:pom:1.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I also try in the core, and get the following error instead:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-core:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/username/Sites/Games/playn-samples/showcase/core/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.googlecode.playn:playn-project:pom:1.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase:1.0-SNAPSHOT, /Users/username/Sites/Games/playn-samples/showcase/pom.xml, line 6, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Still kinda lost. Any ideas?

Comment: The error in each case says that Maven could not find a related POM.  Have you validated that?  Have you tried invoking Maven with the `-e` and `-X` flags as suggested?

Comment: Somehow, running it with -e -X made the whole thing work. Not sure how stack tracing would have fixed it, but there you go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've just updated the way the Java backend is invoked via Maven. You should check out the latest GettingStarted instructions on the PlayN wiki.

However, this should also solve your problems:

```
cd playn-samples
git pull
cd showcase
mvn test -Ptest-java
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try doing a clean install

```
git pull
mvn clean install
```

might work

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Eclipse instructions for MVN](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted#Generating_a_skeleton_project_with_Eclipse). I tried them, and as of a couple of days ago, everything is working flawlessly.

Comment: Do you get an error with code completion on Eclipse ? I followed the same instructions and having errors now.